# Retaining session state during postback from another domain

Tags: asp.net, security, session, webforms

We have an ASP.NET WebForms (designed for mobile) application that, as one of the functions, posts images to our back-end DB. This works without any problems with Windows Phone and Android and posts directly to the DB. With the iPain (iPhone and iPad) we can't post directly to the DB but have to use a third party app that uploads the image and then posts back to our server. To ensure that the session state is preserved we capture this as

```
 Dim vSession As HttpSessionState = HttpContext.Current.Session
        Dim vSessionID As String = vSession.SessionID
```

and this is then sent as part of the upload string

```
vURL += "cookies=ASP.NET_SessionId=" & vSessionID & ";CurrentHOA=" & CurrentCustomerValues & "&"
```

and returned as cookies, but users are getting kicked out of the secure section and back to the login page as soon as the image saving process is complete.

We are using forms authentication for the secure section - the postback from the third party app is sent to a non-secure section (but still maintaining https) where the session should be restored and the user redirected to the start page in the secure section again.

At first we were having problems with the POST not returning, but turned out to be a FriendlyURL issue (we were posting to OurPage.aspx instead of OurPage and the POST string was empty).

Any help in diagnosing this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "asp.net mobile application" and why it can't work in Ipad??

Comment: Sorry - should have said it's an ASP.NET WebForms application designed for mobile use. iPad won't upload images directly to the server - it would appear to be just another drawback to using Apple hardware/software - so users have to use a third party app (downloaded from the Apple store) that uploads to them, then posts back to our server..........

Comment: you really didn't mention why IPad users can't upload images from there deceives, also please edit you question and clarify this point about asp.net web mobile application

Comment: I really can't understand your problem, what is the name of this 3rd party app and how it is getting the session id at the first place, and actually how do you browse the website on the Ipad at the first place , do you open it on safari or what, and if this is the case how do you upload photos on other devices

Comment: I've edited the question - don't understand 'users can't upload images from there deceives' I explained why Apple software won't upload directly to our DB like other mobile devices

Comment: This is the third party app http://www.aurigma.com/aurigma-up/developer/api-code-designer - the session variables are added as cookies

Comment: sorry, some mistyping, I meant devices instead of deceives

Comment: OMG, this is why you can't upload images from Ipad/Iphone apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15209/why-cant-i-upload-pics-on-certain-sites

Comment: I think I know now why this is happening, let me checkout something first

Comment: what .net version you are using

Comment: I understand we can't upload directly  - hence using the third party app in the middle. It works and we get the image saved to the DB but the session state is not being properly restored and the user is getting kicked out of the secure section. We use the same principle in an existing (much older webforms app) and that doesn't have this issue

Comment: It's built using 4.5.1 but 'appears' to be running as 4.0 on IIS 7 on Server 2008 R2

Comment: that's because the runtime for the 4.5.1 is 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this with .net new versions because the cookie contains some token that I really can't remember for now which will prevent you from using this kind of action I will try to search more about this later

Comment: Thank you :-) I will check back later